primeng editor not loading after angular 17 upgrade
I updated my project from angular 16 to 17. After the upgrade, the prime-ng editor component that uses quill (updated from v1.3.7 to v2.0.2) is failing to render with the following error on the browser console -
this.dynamicQuill is not a constructor
(anonymous) @   primeng-editor.mjs:179

Any pointers to resolve this?

please share angular and primeng exact versions also delete .angular, node_modules and package-lock.json do a fresh install and check once

@angular/core - 17.3.12
primeng - 17.18.11
I have tried clearing .angular, node_modules and package-lock.json, but that did not help

issue not reproducible stackblitz

I too tried to reproduce this in a separate app but couldn't. Any pointers that you can provide on how to debug this?

in the separate app, copy paste your src/app content and check if the issue happens, then the problem is in your code, check the stacktrace for easy debugging

Is there a way I can get the debug version of prime-ng inside my app to be able to debug the same?

open chrome inspector, click on the file that gives the error in comsole., place a debugger and refresh, after that the breakpoint will fire, then check the stacktrace

project is using webpack that I was unaware of. excluding quill from shared plugins resolved the issue.

do post answer so that it helps someone in future! great!

The project is using webpack. Excluding quill from the shared plugins resolves the mentioned issue.
